# .desktop file no longer working after adding another .desktop file

Tags: 20.04, .desktop, desktop-icons

I created a `.desktop` file to launch an application and saved it to my `~/Desktop` folder. It was working until I added another `.desktop` file. The original `.desktop` file no longer shows it's configured icon and when I click it just opens in a text editor. Same behavior with the new file. The 'Allow Launching' option is not available when I right-click on the file. In the file properties it has my text editor listed as the default application. Is that correct? Is there another reason why this might not be working?

The `.desktop` files work fine if I add them to `~/.local/share/applications`

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Edit: The solution by @Matigo worked except instead of dragging the `.desktop` file directly onto the desktop I had to open my `~/Desktop` folder in Nautilus and drag it there. Then I was able to right click and select Allow Launching.

Edit: After further experimenting I found that I could add a new .desktop file manually without using `desktop-file-install`. If I created a new .desktop file and saved it directly to `~/Desktop` then it would work fine. Or if I created the .desktop file in my home dir and dragged it from there it would also work. What doesn't work, and causes all existing shortcuts to stop working, is to drag a .desktop file from a folder in a different partition. I'm not sure why that breaks things but that's what I found. To restore just delete all .desktop files in `~/Desktop` and add them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you’ll need to use `desktop-file-install`:

1. Copy the application launcher to your home directory so that it’s `~/{name}.desktop` (Changing `{name}` to that’s really the file name is)
2. From the terminal, run: `sudo desktop-file-install {name}.desktop`. 
    This will verify the `.desktop` file and install it to `/usr/share/applications`.
3. Open Nautilus and navigate to `/usr/share/applications`
4. Find the icon for the launcher (`{name}.desktop`) and drag the icon to your desktop

Then do this with the second `.desktop` file. It’s annoying, but it works.

Comment: It works up until step 4. It won't let me drag the icon to the desktop. @matigo

Comment: But it works if I open the Desktop folder in Nautilus and drag it there. Thanks!